# Insert query is not working

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Database connection is  working .But something wrong with my insert query.here is the insert query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Address(Name,TelNo1,Address,TelNo2,TelNo3) " +
    "VALUES('" +
    _name      + "','" +
    _tel1      + "','" +
    _address   + "','" +
    _tel2      + "','" +
    _tel3      + ")";
```

i couldn't find the error please help me to fix this
i am using VS 2010 and **MSsql 2008.**

Comment: [A good read on how to write your queries](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries). A hint: not using string concatenation.

Comment: The question says MSSQL while the tags say MySQL. Which is it? :)

Comment: After you fix the problem, and after you prevent SQL injection attacks, you should look at your database structure.  Having repeating fields like `TelNo1`, `TelNo2`, and `TelNo3` is poor practice; look at *normalization* for details. Try to go to third normal form at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your connection whether it is open and check connection string
[how to write insert query in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954900/how-to-write-insert-query-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Missing `'` at the last:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Address(Name,TelNo1,Address,TelNo2,TelNo3) VALUES('"+ _name +"','"+ _tel1 +"','"+ _address +"','"+ _tel2 +"','"+ _tel3 +"')";
```

Comment: Try to run the query directly on MySQL administrator, and see what error comes

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an apostrophe `'` at the end:

```
+"')"
```

Also, you might want to consider using the  [MySQL adapter for ADO.Net](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).  Should be easier than constructing SQL statements by hand, and mitigate against SQL injection attacks (if that's relevant to your case).

Comment: And using parameters would also have *entirely mitigated this issue*!

Comment: Sounds strange to use the MySQL adapter for MSSQL...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ha ... I'm tired.